# PHP Exchange 2007 Server SMTP, NTLM Authentication Realm

Tags: php, smtp, exchange-server, ntlm

I am trying to connect to a hosted Exchange setup at sherweb.com via. PHP using SMTP w/ NTLM authentication.  When connecting I need to enter the NTLM Authentication Realm.

I am receiving the following error from the PHP script, "The requested credential workstation is not defined"  I am using the SMTP class and SASL class from phpclasses.org for the NTLM authentication.

How do I find the NTLM Authentication Realm?  Tech. Support at sherweb.com is like talking to a brick wall, if it is not in their knowledge base then they don't have a clue.

**UPDATE**

I understand I could use the Exchange 2007 Web Services however I tried some sample code regarding that and it seems the Exchange WDSL has errors.  Essentially I would prefer to use SMTP if possible via. the NTLM auth.